# how to handle user with type and each type with different data fields in eloquent way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have a table for **users** with column **type** which can be for example **type1 type2 type3** then each type has different type of fields.

**type1** has 3 fields a1 a2 a3.....

**type2** has 12 fields  b1 b2 b3 b4.....

**type3** has has 5 fields c1 c2 c3.....

assuming in future there maybe more fields in each type of table.

how to handle this situation in eloquent way?

I have 2 solution right now but I don't think that is accurate

**Solution 1:** single table with type details and add column into it for each fields which can make a lot of column like for now it will be 25 30 .....

**Solution 2:** to make 3 different table for each type but how will be able to handle it how will the relationship.

**Solution 3:** make user_details table with key and value for each input with auth()->user_id.

Comment: Not every object-oriented pattern is going to map to a database well. You may need to re-think your design here.

Comment: i can have a 3rd table with key and value i just want the db to be optimize for future.

Comment: This sounds the opposite of optimized. It goes against the grain of how an RDBMS is  normally used, and while you might be able to pull this off, it will be extremely convoluted. Try and keep it simple: A core table with others you can join in based on type.

Answer (score 0):

you can design a `many to many` relation in this case.

read [laravel many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

use `laravel Gates` to give each data for each user.
in `laravel Gates` you can define conditions and use it in your controller.

read [laravel gates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#gates)